# Python: namespaces in xml ElementTree (or lxml)

Tags: python, xml, namespaces, elementtree

I want to retrieve a legacy xml file, manipulate and save it.

Here is my code:

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
NS = "{http://www.somedomain.com/XI/Traffic/10}"

def fix_xml(filename):
    f = ET.parse(filename)
    root = f.getroot()
    eventlist = root.findall("%(ns)Event" % {'ns':NS })
    xpath = "%(ns)sEventDetail/%(ns)sEventDescription" % {'ns':NS }
    for event in eventlist:
        desc = event.find(xpath)
        desc.text = desc.text.upper() # do some editting to the text.

    ET.ElementTree(root, nsmap=NS).write("out.xml", encoding="utf-8")


shorten_xml("test.xml")
```

The file I load contains:

```
xmlns="http://www.somedomain.com/XI/Traffic/10"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.somedomain.com/XI/Traffic/10 10.xds"
```

at the root tag.

I have the following problems, related to namespace:

- As you see, for each tag call, I have give the namespace at the begining to retreive a child.
- Generated xml file doesn't have `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` at the begining.
- The tags at the output contains such `<ns0:eventDescription>` while I need output as the original `<eventDescription>`, without namespace at the begining.

How can these be solved?

Comment: "How can these be solved?" - dont use Python's lxml. maybe try XSLT, for example [Remove all namespace attributes from xml using xmlstarlet](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/720658/remove-all-namespace-attributes-from-xml-using-xmlstarlet)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at the [lxml tutorial section on namespaces](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces). Also this [article about namespaces in ElementTree](https://web.archive.org/web/20200721203629/http://effbot.org/zone/element-namespaces.htm).

Problem 1: Put up with it, like everybody else does. Instead of `"%(ns)Event" % {'ns':NS }` try `NS+"Event"`.

Problem 2: By default, the XML declaration is written only if it is required. You can force it (lxml only) by using `xml_declaration=True` in your `write()` call.

Problem 3: The `nsmap` arg appears to be lxml-only. AFAICT it needs a MAPping, not a string. Try `nsmap={None: NS}`. The effbot article has a section describing a workaround for this.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions in order:

- you can't just ignore the namespace, not in the path syntax that `.findall()` uses , but not in "real" xpath (supported by lxml) either: there you'd still be forced to use a prefix, and still need to provide some prefix-to-uri mapping.
- use `xml_declaration=True` as well as `encoding='utf-8'` with the `.write()` call (available in lxml, but in stdlib xml.etree only since python 2.7 I believe)
- I believe lxml will do behave like you want