# Python XML parser renames namespace variables

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I have been using xml.etree.ElementTree to parse a Word XML document. After making my changes I use `tree.write('test.xml')` to write the tree to a file. Once the XML is saved, Word was unable to read the file. Looking at the XML, it appears that the new XML has all of the namespaces renamed.

For example, w:t became ns2:t

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

tree = ET.parse('FL0809spec2.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

l = [' ',' ']
prev = None
count = 0

for t in root.iter('{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}t'):
    l[0] = l[1]
    l[1] = t.text
    if(l[0] <> '' and l[1] <> '' and re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]', l[0][len(l[0]) - 1]) and re.search(r'[a-z]', l[1][0])):
        words = re.findall(r'(\b\w+\b)(\W+)',l[1])
        if(len(words) > 0):
            prev.text = prev.text + words[0][0]
            t.text = t.text[len(words[0][0]):]
            count += 1
    prev = t

tree.write('FL0809spec2Improved.xml')
```

Comment: a) If your code doesn't do any changes, just writes straight back out, do the namespace names change? b) as long as the namespace definition is the same, in XML terms I don't think it should matter what the namespace actual name is - the problem may be word not ElementTree

Comment: As you can see in your code, in ElemenTree the reference to the namespace for t is not the name in the physical XML, it's the namespace URI.

Comment: Is there a way to force ElementTree to use the same namespace reference as the original?

Comment: Dunno - go look at the source?

Comment: Looks like lxml may be give more control over namespace prefixes (apparently the correct term is prefix) see http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces and nsmap - and other than that I believe lxml has v.similar API to ElementTree so may not need other changes

Comment: and see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886189/python-namespaces-in-xml-elementtree-or-lxml

Comment: and page 8 of http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pylxml/pylxml.pdf

Comment: It's completely irrelevant what the namespace prefixes are, as long as the namespace URI is the same. The error must be caused by something else.

Comment: Alright, I'll look further. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Tomalak in XML terms, yes. MS Word may expect the same prefixes, though. Stranger things have happened.

Comment: @Tomalak yep as I suspected, the culprit is Word - it appears to require specific namespaces prefixes, or at least it accepts a XML doc read/written through lxml where they haven't been changed, but won't accept the same dox read/written through xml.etree.ElementTree where the prefixes are changed. Might I suppose be that it rejects the XML when just one specific prefix has been changed. Who knows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that:

a) Python built-in xml.etree.ElementTree is not idempotent (transparent) - if you read an XML file and then immediately write out the xml, the output is different from the input. The namespace prefixes are changed, for example. Also the initial ?xml and ?mso tags are removed. There may be other differences. The removal of the two initial tags doesn't seem to matter, so it's something about the rest of the XML that Word doesn't like.

and b) MS Word expects the namespaces to be written with exactly the same prefixes as the xml files it generates - IMO this is very poor (if not appalling) style because in pure XML terms it is the namespace URI that defines the namespace, not the prefix used to reference it, but hey ho that's the way it seems to work.

As long as you don't mind installing lxml, to solve your problem is very easy. Happily lxml.etree.ElementTree appears to be a lot more determined than xml.etree.ElementTree about not changing anything when writing what it has read, at least it maintains the prefixes that were read in, and those first two tags are written too.

So to use lxml:

Install xlmx with pip:

```
pip install lxml
```

Change the first line of your code from:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
```

to:

```
from lxml import etree as ET
```

Then (in my testing of your code with the changey bits between reading and writing the xml removed) the output document can be opened without error in MS Word :-)

Comment: That the `?xml and ?mso` "tags" (those aren't really tags) are removed is **much** more likely the culprit than the namespace prefix change. Namespace prefixes effectively do not exist anymore after XML parsing, and Word does not get the document before parsing has happened. In any case, ElementTree is an incomplete XML implementation, I agree that you should ditch it (and keep that fact in mind for future work with XML).

Comment: I tried removing them from the original xml document word wrote, and it read in the document just fine - so no, removing the ?xml and ?mso not-tags doesn't appear to matter to Word. How about trying it yourself before guessing/speculating about any other possible causes? I know the namespace prefixes don't matter in pure XML terms - go tell that to Microsoft. Or try it yourself, prove me wrong.

Comment: I'm not speculating, I know how XML works. But, if you insist: I've just opened a DOCX file, changed all the namespace prefixes from "w:" to "y:" inside `word\document.xml`, saved it back, loaded it in Word and got a clean document, no errors, no complaints, it just works. The namespace prefix is irrelevant.

Comment: I tried a document written as .xml, not a docx - the OP didn’t mention docx. I’m repeating that I’m not saying renaming the prefixes is bad XML - maybe it’s something else about xml.etree.ElementTree read/writing the xml. Try it yourself running OP’s python (without the processing bits) using xml.etree.ElementTree and lxml.etree.ElementTrre. Try deleting the non-tags. The lxml-processed version works, the non-tags don’t matter, the xml.etree.ElementTree-processed version doesn’t load into Word.

Comment: This fixed my issue. Thanks a lot!